# navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem margin in iOS7

Tags: ios7

For some reason the right button in the navigation bar is 16px from the right. I'd like to make the margin smaller. What's the proper way to do that?

```
self.btnDone = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
UIImage *btnImgDone = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_small_default.png"];
self.btnDone.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:15.0];
[self.btnDone setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.btnDone setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.btnDone setTitleShadowColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:.2f] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
self.btnDone.titleLabel.shadowOffset = (CGSize){0,-1};
[self.btnDone setBackgroundImage:btnImgDone forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.btnDone setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_small_active.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];  

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:self.btnDone];
```

[image]

Comment: Did you find any answer in the meantime?

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue and the only way i found to fix it was to use the `setImageEdgeInsets:`.

If you want to move your button to the right (for example : 5 pts or 10 px), add the following line to the button declaration :

```
UIEdgeInsets buttonEdges = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, -5);
[self.btnDone setImageEdgeInsets:buttonEdges];
```

If you want to support iOS6 and iOS7 you can do this :

```
CGFloat xOffset;

if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0f)
{
    // for ios7
    xOffset = 5.0f;
}
else
{
    // ios6
    xOffset = 2.0f;
}

UIEdgeInsets buttonEdges = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, xOffset, 0, - xOffset);
[self.btnDone setImageEdgeInsets:buttonEdges];
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: But would this work if I use a backgroundImage for the button? Because the background will be squeezed.

Comment: My mistake, i didn't see you were using the `setBackgroundImage:forState:`, `setImageEdgeInsets:` works for me but i'm using the `setImage:forState:` (it doesn't squeeze it though).

Answer (score 6):

Try to put a fixed space after that button:

```
// Fixed space
UIBarButtonItem *fixedSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
[fixedSpace setWidth:20.0];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = @[fixedSpace, yourButton];
```

The whole code I've used is:

```
// Bar button
UIButton *loadButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 15, 34)];
VVdLoadImage *loadImage = [[VVdLoadImage alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 15, 34)];
loadImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
loadImage.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
[loadButton addSubview:loadImage];

[loadButton addTarget:self action:@selector(loadCards) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
UIBarButtonItem *loadBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:loadButton];

UIBarButtonItem *fixedSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
[fixedSpace setWidth:20.0];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = @[fixedSpace, loadButton];
```

Comment: I tried that but the result was just less space for my button. Margin on the right remained.

Comment: I've tested it again with different values of setWidth an it works for me.

Comment: It works when I use a UIButton without a background image. Did yours have a background image and button title text?

Comment: Is a UIButton where I've added a image as subview. I've modified my previous answer to show the code.

Answer (score 1):

See mine.

```
func addLogOutButtonToNavigationBar(triggerToMethodName: String)
{
    let button: UIButton = UIButton()
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "logOff.png"), forState: .Normal)
    button.frame = CGRectMake(20, 0, 30, 25)
    button.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets.init(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: -10)

    button .addTarget(self, action:Selector(triggerToMethodName), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    let rightItem:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem()
    rightItem.customView = button
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightItem
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you still can't get it working, for some reason this worked for me. someButton is the UIButton that I've added as a customView of my UIBarButtonItem

```
someButton.contentEdgeInsets = (UIEdgeInsets){.right=-20};
```